# how to fix this exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, keystore, private-key

exception is :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.security.cert.Certificate; cannot be cast to [Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate;

in keystore.jks file, it has one entry, its alias is "/btsmed-1/certh-1/necert-1", certificate chain in this keystore.jks file was set into by this method:

```
keystore.setKeyEntry(alias, Keys.keyPair().getPrivate(),KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray(), certChain);
keystore.store(out, KEY_STORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
```

before I re-load jks to keystore, when execute this statement:

```
X509Certificate[] certs1 = (X509Certificate[])keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
```

it will not throw cast exception.

but after keystore.load(fIn, password); it will throw cast exception when execute this statement:

```
X509Certificate[] certs1 = (X509Certificate[]) keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
```

====================below is source code.

```
public class KeystoreLoad {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      char[] password = "nokia123".toCharArray();
      String alias = "/btsmed-1/certh-1/necert-1";

      KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

      keystore.load(null, null);

      FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream("d://keystore/keystore.jks");

      keystore.load(fIn, password);

      X509Certificate[] certs1 = (X509Certificate[]) keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(certs1));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the java compiler doesn't know if all the objects in the `Certificate[]` returned by the `getCertificateChain()` method contains only `X509Certificate` [even though the `X509Certificate` is the only class that extends the `Certificate` class as of now].

So if you need the `X509Certificate[]` you have to loop through the `Certificate[]`, like below:

```
Certificate[] certChain = ks.getCertificateChain("ALIAS");

X509Certificate[] x509CertChain = new X509Certificate[certChain.length];
for (int i = 0; i < certChain.length; i++)
    x509CertChain[i] = (X509Certificate) certChain[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class TestDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        char[] password = "nokia123".toCharArray();
        String alias = "/btsmed-1/certh-1/necert-1";

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        keystore.load(null, null);

        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream("d://keystore/keystore.jks");

        keystore.load(fIn, password);
        keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        X509Certificate[] certs1 = (X509Certificate[]) keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(certs1));

    }

}
```

got it insted of imporing javax.security.cert.X509Certificate use 
 java.security.cert.X509Certificate

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I want to transfer the Certificate[] to type X509Certificate[], and I don't know why it will cast failed.

Comment: try the modified one

Comment: X509Certificate[] certs1 = (X509Certificate[]) keystore.getCertificateChain(alias); use the same but change the import